# Use throw_with_nested and catch nested exception

Tags: c++, c++11, try-catch

I really like std::throw_with_nested in c++11 since it emulates java's printStackTrace() but right now I am just curious how to catch a nested exception, for example:

```
void f() {
    try {
        throw SomeException();
    } catch( ... ) {
        std::throw_with_nested( std::runtime_error( "Inside f()" ) );
    }
}
void g() {
    try {
        f();
    } catch( SomeException & e ) { // I want to catch SomeException here, not std::runtime_error, :(
        // do something
    }
}
```

Previously, I thought std::throw_with_nested generates a new exception which is multiply derived from two exceptions (std::runtime_error and SomeException) but after reading some online tutorial, it encapsulates SomeException within std::exception_ptr and it's probabaly why I canonot catch it.

Then I realized I can fix this by using std::rethrow_if_nested( e ) but the above case is only two level which is easy to handle but thinking about more general situation like 10 level folded and I just don't want to write std::rethrow_if_nested 10 times to handle it.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: Instead of repeating something 10 times, write a loop or a recursive function.

Comment: The exception is multiply derived from `std::runtime_error` and `std::nested_exception`, but NOT `SomeException`.

Answer (score 6):

Unwrapping a `std::nested_exception` is readily accomplished via recursion:

```
template<typename E>
void rethrow_unwrapped(const E& e)
{
    try {
        std::rethrow_if_nested(e);
    } catch(const std::nested_exception& e) {
        rethrow_unwrapped(e);
    } catch(...) {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Where usage would look something like this:

```
try {
    throws();
} catch(const std::exception& e) {
    try {
        rethrow_unwrapped(e);
    } catch (const SomeException& e) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

A demo of this in action can be found [here](https://ideone.com/peUiKs).

Comment: Is your `e` In the first function shadowed/shadowing?

Comment: Yes, within the nested catch block, `e` is shadowed.